# How do they add you to their blacklist?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, paper-submission, rejection

I have heard if you send papers to a journal/conferences there are some conditions that might be dangerous for you academic progress! I researched about it but I wasn't able to find a good definition to be aware. My main question is how they add an author to black list and how is the procedure? moreover, what is the reaction to original researches which might be weak or bad written? I know they will reject but is this the end or they will mention your prior effort in future?

My research field: Computer Science

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, but it seems you are worried about being blacklisted for submitting a weak/bad paper. Blacklisting is generally reserved for academic misconduct (concurrent submission, plagiarism, falsifying results, etc.). So, as long as you are submitting in good faith and follow academic norms, you should be fine.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks. You've realized my concern correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of *black lists* to prevent low quality submissions in academia is pretty rare. I have never heard of a journal or conference having a formal *black list* procedure. The first I ever heard of a formal *black list* system was the one implemented by [EPSRC](https://www.epsrc.ac.uk/funding/applicationprocess/basics/resubpol/rua/) in 2010. There was a discussion of the system published in [Nature](http://www.nature.com/news/2010/100324/full/464474a.html) soon after it was implemented. Basically, the system works as follows, if a PI had 3 proposals that were either not scored or scored in the bottom 50% in the last 2 years, they are only allowed to submit one application as a PI for a 12 month period. Grants submitted where you are a CI do not count against you and even when *black listed* you can be listed on an unlimited number of applications as a CI.

The fact that formal black lists are not frequently used, does not mean that submitting low quality work does not hurt your reputation. It is quite likely that if reviewers frequently see low quality work from a researcher that they will have a negative bias towards future work from that person/group. The opposite holds for individuals who consistently produce high quality work and sometimes get the *benefit of the doubt*. In fact, I think these biases are one of the reasons for a double blind review system.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something egregiously bad, or are extremely abusive towards the journal, then they might blacklist you. But you need to do something exceptional. Simply submitting bad papers won't get you blacklisted (since desk rejection doesn't usually take long), and neither does submitting poorly written papers (which are even easier to handle since they just send you a "unable to understand your paper" email, which they might even have a standard version of). It's usually to the journal's advantage to receive potentially-publishable papers, after all.

Here's [a real life example](https://retractionwatch.com/2014/04/10/following-personal-attacks-and-threats-elsevier-plant-journal-makes-author-persona-non-grata/) of a journal banning someone from submitting. The person in question is [Jaime A. Teixeira da Silva](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=dWCOqCkAAAAJ), a plant scientist who has received 21974 citations as of time of writing. *Scientia Horticulturae* cited personal attacks and threats for their decision. One of the emails sent to the journal's editors and cc'ed to other scientists was:

> I will expose your fraud to every scientist I know, and make my case public from now on that corruption and fraud, lack of professionalism and libel are the four corner-stones for the publishing frame-work by Elsevier and this journal, Scientia Horticulturae.

da Silva also wrote this:

> Moreover, if I do not see a resignation [by either of the journal's two editors-in-chief] in 72 hours, I will immediately post this libelous case of editorial bias and witch-hunting on Retraction Watch and other blogs.
>
> MOREOVER, IF I DO NOT RECEIVE A CONFIRMATION, WITH PROOF, OF STANDARD AND UNIFORM INQUIRY TO ALL AUTHORS, AS WELL AS A RESPONSE TO THE NEXT 8 QUESTIONS, I WILL CONTACT ALL SCIENTIA HORTICULTURAE AUTHORS AND ALSO THE INSTITUTES TO WHICH ALL SCIENTIA HORTICULTURAE EDITORS BELONG.

As for the procedure itself, I imagine the publisher would add a note to your profile in their editorial management system that you are blacklisted and all your submissions are to be rejected without review.